How do I add a custom field when sending events with the PagerDuty Events API?
I want to create a custom field and add it to events I create with the events API: https://support.pagerduty.com/main/docs/custom-fields-on-incidents. I'm not using orchestration.
I'm using the events API and I see no option for custom fields: https://developer.pagerduty.com/api-reference/368ae3d938c9e-send-an-event-to-pager-duty
I want to use this custom field to add info to the PD incidents when they are generated for users to see so it can't happen after the incident is create from the event.
If I have to make multiple API calls to create an event, get the incident that the event generated, then update the incident with a custom field it will have no utility for me.
Is this how this is suppose to work?
